# Kivy pyjnius with Buildozer - Adding jnius to the app causes it to crash after starting it

Tags: android, python, kivy, python-3.5, pyjnius

after adding these lines of code to my kivy app, when i start it on my android 4.4.4 the app immediately crashes

```
from jnius import autoclass
try:
    Environment = autoclass('android.os.Environment')
    sdpath = Environment.get_running_app().getExternalStorageDirectory()

# Not on Android
except:
    sdpath = App.get_running_app().user_data_dir
```

I checked ADB to see if any errors come up but nothing came up except

`03-01 17:44:19.813: E/InputDispatcher(898): channel '437f0100 org.renpy.android.PythonActivity (s)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!`

**EDIT**

It seems the line `sdpath = Environment.get_running_app().getExternalStorageDirectory()` is the one causing the crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I checked adb logcat and observed that `Environment.get_running_app().getExternalStorageDirectory()` raises

> AttributeError: type object 'android.os.Environment' has no attribute 'get_running_app'

Use 
`sdpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that was the problem. Quick question, is ADB logcat different from normal ADB?

Comment: Check this out http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/01/handy-adb-commands-for-android.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
from kivy.app import platform
...
if platform() == 'android':
    DATA_FOLDER = os.getenv('EXTERNAL_STORAGE')
```

**Also** include this in your buildozer spec:

```
requirements = kivy, pyjnius
```

Comment: i will still need pyjnius for other things so i would prefer fixing this if it's possible

Comment: Can you provide in your Question the minimum amount of lines that produce the error,  just **import pyjnius** also crashes?

Comment: No, just importing it will not cause the crash, if i add those with the actual usage, my application will crash on start on my android phone.